# MS Azure - python http.server - Connection refused

Tags: python, azure, prometheus, python-server-pages

I have a very simple Ubuntu VM hosted on MS Azure. I have this simple python program running on it:

```
import http.server
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
from prometheus_client import Counter

REQUESTS  = Counter('hello_worlds_total','Hello World requested')

class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        REQUESTS.inc()
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("Hello world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_http_server(8001)
    server = http.server.HTTPServer(('localhost',8000), MyHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
}}}
```

when I hit from my PC the url http://VM_AZURE_IP:8001 it replies with Promethues output. When I try http://VM_AZURE_IP:8000 I get connection refused. The newtork rules are ok, if I switch `start_http_server(8001)` to `start_http_server(8000)` and `http.server.HTTPServer(('localhost',8000), MyHandler)` to `http.server.HTTPServer(('localhost',8001), MyHandler)`, I get promethues metrics hitting http://VM_AZURE_IP:8000 and connection refused on port 8001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your code like this and make sure you have added the port 8001,8000 in the inbound rule of your NSG associated to the Ubuntu VM.

```
import http.server
from prometheus_client import start_http_server
from prometheus_client import Counter

REQUESTS  = Counter('hello_worlds_total','Hello World requested')

class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        REQUESTS.inc()
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b"Hello world")   # add b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_http_server(8000)
    server = http.server.HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0',8001), MyHandler)  # chang to IP address 0.0.0.0
    print("server on!")
    server.serve_forever()
```

It worked on my side.

[image]